# My text view is null

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a flashcard app. This is just one of the decks I have made. I copy-pasted this from another activity I made and that activity which has 99% of the same code works perfectly.
Log cat throws an odd exception. it says the text view I'm trying to set is null.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.flashcards.flashcards.CardAnswer2.onStart(CardAnswer2.java:27)
```

The method in question

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();  // Always call the superclass method first
    int w=0;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(CardQuestion2.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView showAnswer= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerTitle2);
    showAnswer.setText(message);
```

It throws the exception at the set text and when I tried to debug it. It told me showAnswer is null

Xml file if it helps

```
 <TextView android:text="@string/answer2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/answerTitle2"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/wrong1"
    android:id="@+id/wrong2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/right1"
    android:id="@+id/right2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
     />
```

Comment: Please show us how you deflate the XML and initialize the view. Did you accidentally reference the wrong layout resource?

Comment: I got it I just set the wrong content View

Comment: I cant see setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);